# How many sites per pool in IIS8

Tags: windows-server-2012, application-pools, iis-8

I am migrating a old server to a new box and i am attempting to clean it up.  This box has 600+ sites running on it.  I wanted to know what the best practices would be for site pooling.  These sites are for small businesses and some get more traffic then others.  I was thinking that high traffic sites should get there own pool. Is that correct?

How many low traffic sites can you put in 1 pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a best practice per se, but there are some considerations; some of which you've already thought of, such as traffic.  The other considerations are CPU and RAM usage from the resulting traffic to these sites.  Generally I like to separate sites on their own Application Pools if at all possible.  But in your case you've got 600+ sites, you'll likely end up sharing some pools.  The downside of this is that if you have to do maintenance on one site and it requires any sort of recycling or stopping and/or editing of the pools then you'll affect all sites sharing that pool.  What I'd do is find a way to break them all down to a group of pools based on traffic and then go from there.  Low, Medium, and Large traffic if you can.  I'd first recommend reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carmelop/archive/2013/03/22/how-many-web-applications-per-application-pool.aspx).

There's no rule or policy stating that you have to have 1 site per pool for best performance, however, the more separation the better.